# Portrait Layout is shown properly only after changing the orientation to Landscape and back to Portrait

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin, xamarin.ios, autolayout

I have a simple layout with multiple views and constraints to position and size them as I need. When I deploy the app to a simulator or device, the X, Y and Widths of all the views have the proper sizes. The Height on the other hand is always 0. All the views have proportional heights according to the super view.

Now, if I flip the orientation to Landscape and then back to portrait, everything shows up properly (the heights are no longer 0).

I've used the same logic with proportional heights previously, and I started seeing this problem with newly created view controllers after updating to Xcode 7.

**EDIT** You can get the .xib from: http://1drv.ms/1M81EUQ

Comment: Need more information on how your constraints are set up - can you share code or storyboard file? It sounds like you're missing a constraint.

Comment: Are you changing anything about the concerned views in code? It sounds to me, like you are adding some content that determines the height in code, but the views are not redrawn until the device rotates. Maybe you forgot a layoutIfNeeded somewhere?

Comment: @ProgrammingBonn no, I'm not changing anything in code. I just have the layout in a XIB and just loading that.

Comment: @Ben I edited the question to add a link to the .xib file.

Answer (score 1):

you have to Set different view update method call regarding the orientation changed  if you use auto mask resizing or used autolayout to fix this .

Comment: Not sure I correctly understand what you mean, but I am using Auto Layout if that's what you're suggesting.

Comment: i thought  you have not set a fix height and width of IBoutlet you are taken in your view. and please set the bottom spacing equal or less .

Comment: Not sure I understand. Do you mind editing the .xib file that is linked in the question and modifying it then attach it somewhere so I can see what you mean? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your .xib was configured with Size Classes enabled, but your views and constraints were all configured to only be applied for Compact width, Regular height.

[image: wC hR is Checked, Any Any is not]

I went through and changed the views and constraints to apply to Any width, Any height, and this resolved the issue with landscape layouts.

[Download the modified .xib file here](http://1drv.ms/1P0SQH7)

I recommend using Xcode 7's Preview Assistant View when working with Autolayout, as it will let you see multiple devices, in multiple orientations at the same time. This really helped in this case with showing that the layout was fine in portrait, but not in landscape.

This is what I saw in your .xib as you provided
[image: Preview of populated portrait but empty landscape views]

And with the changes in my .xib
[image: Preview showing populated portrait and landscape]

How could this have happened? One way is that you may have accidentally set the storyboard editor to a specific size class. If you see a blue border at the bottom of the editor, anything you add will be configured to be only installed for that specific size class. You can click on the size class shown to change it out to w Any h Any to return to the default mode.

[image: Blue bar at the bottom of the storyboard editor]

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look at it. Though my issue wasn't that it did not work in landscape mode (this page will only be used in portrait). The problem is, in order to show the portrait page properly, I need to do an orientation change so when it switches back to portrait, everything shows up correctly. Also, the previews for portrait are all fine, the issues only appear when you run it on an actual device or simulator.